# How to achieve multiple sources mid-stream in gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a situation where I need to pull files from numerous folders through a pipeline of tasks ultimately resulting in a single file.

Suppose I have two different types of sources, source type A and B. "A" sources need to be uglified/minified, while B sources do not (they already are.) Ultimately, I want both A and B to be concatenated together. How can this be achieved with gulp and gulp plugins?

```
var aSources = gulp.src(...)
                   .pipe(uglify());
var bSources = gulp.src(...);

return ?????.pipe(concat(...)).pipe(gulp.dest(...));
```

I've tried using the event-stream plugin to merge the two streams: this causes the "a" stream to be replayed on the merge, so the result is the a stream in duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "merge-stream"

```
mergeStream([streamA, streamB]).pipe(concat(...))...
```

Or "gulp-if":

```
gulp.src([sources])
    .pipe(gulpIf(/[.]js$/, uglify))
    .pipe(concat(...))
```

Or "gulp-add-src":

```
gulp.src(source1).pipe(uglify()).pipe(gulAddSrc(source2))
```

Comment: The first solution doesn't work for the reasons I mentioned in the OP. Second solution feels more like a hack. Third solution looks like a winner, though I'm sad it doesn't come core with gulp! Thanks!

Comment: @MartinBliss how are you using `merge-stream`? The "replay" behavior sounds suspicious.

Comment: @terinjokes I'm using the defaults and calling the function exactly like many examples would have me with two arguments, one for each source stream. Of course when the streams are created they execute immediately and then on merge stream, each streams pipe is executed again.